# Turtlebot with Groovy failed

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I've got following error with turtlebot_bringup, in ROS Groovy.
I have followed http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot.
Anyone succeeded to run turtlebot in Groovy?

```
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot_create/create_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py:56: UserWarning: roslib.rosenv is deprecated, please use rospkg or rosgraph.rosenv
  import roslib.rosenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/turtlebot_create/create_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py", line 65, in <module>
    from turtlebot_driver import Turtlebot, MAX_WHEEL_SPEED, DriverError
ImportError: No module named turtlebot_driver
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56865/turtlebot-with-groovy-failed./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-03**:
It works with ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Try this version and check.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-03-03**:
I get the same fatal error as @Hyon Lim when using a Create-based TurtleBot.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS and the latest Groovy debs.  The file turtlebot_driver.py does not exist anywhere under /opt/ros/groovy.  It *does* exist under /opt/ros/fuerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Daniel Stonier already provided a solution on Turtlebot SIG:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-turtlebot/To8BAPnLDeA

I copy/paste it here:

If you're using the create base these are only working from the turtlebot_xxx 2.0.0+ deb releases. I backported the turtlebot code to work with the create and bugfixed various things going from 1.9.x to 2.0.x - the first warning you have above is indicative of 1.9.x so I'm guessing that's what you have.

If you want to test the new release immediately. then can you try changing your ubuntu repository to use ros-shadow-fixed and upgrade.

Also make sure to check melonee's advice about the pip installed rospkg, rosdep, rosinstall, vcstools. Keep uninstalling them until nothing is left. I think everyone in our lab has been bitten by that one.

Cheers,
Daniel.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-03-06**:
The error is gone now that I have the turtlebot_xxx 2.0.0+ deb releases on Ubuntu 12.04LTS and I can now teleoperate the Create.  Thanks!